# Keyboard-driven editing sucks on slower machines

Tags: feature-request, editor

I work on a netbook, which isn't top-notch machine and when I compose either a question or an answer and I try to mark chars or words of phrases with:

- Shift+[left/right arrow]
- Ctrl+Shift+[left/right arrow]
- Shift+[up/down arrow]

it's really slow. I mean it's like an order of magnitude slower than I am and I'm not some kind of superhero typist or something.

I don't know if it's the machine which can't cope with heavy scripts or something but it works decently as long as I don't *mark* anything and just move over the editor with arrows or Ctrl+[arrow]. However as long as Shift is involved the editor is on its last legs.

Can we do something about that? If switching to mouse is faster than it doesn't say anything good about the editor.

Comment: Feature request should be a specific request. For example you can ask to not run any scripts when detecting specific OS.

Comment: This sounds like a support request, not a feature request.

Comment: Your problem is probably with your keyboard's key repeat rate. You can correct that in the control panel or settings of your Operating System. But if it really is a problem with a slow PC, then you can also try using the 'end' key to reach the end of a sentence faster.